# Adding node's inner text to List or Array

Tags: vb.net

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse my router's web configuration menu. I use this code to get the data inside the table's cells. How can I add the result to a `List` or `Array`. This is the code:

```
Public Sub TestFunction()
        Dim htmldoc As New HtmlDocument
        htmldoc.LoadHtml(SendRequest())
        Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/tr")

        For Each trs In nodes
            For Each tds In trs.ChildNodes
                Debug.WriteLine(tds.InnerText)'add this output to list or array
            Next
            Debug.WriteLine(" ")
        Next
End Sub
```

Its out put look like:

```
cc:c7:60:79:8c:e9
11921
18509
130
yes
150

2c:d0:5a:47:0a:86
3819722
1917451
81
no
150
```

And I want this data to look like this structure inside an array or something else

```
 0 => {
 datahere
 datahere
 datahere
},
1 => {
 datahere
 datahere
 datahere
}
```

Solution: I know this is crude but is there a better way to do this?

```
Public Sub TestFunction()
        Dim htmldoc As New HtmlDocument
        htmldoc.LoadHtml(SendRequest())
        Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/tr")
        Dim values As New List(Of List(Of String))
        For Each trs In nodes
            Dim lst As New List(Of String)
            For Each tds In trs.ChildNodes
                lst.Add(tds.InnerText)
            Next
            values.Add(lst)
            Debug.WriteLine("")
        Next
        Debug.WriteLine(values.Item(0).Item(0))
    End Sub
```

Comment: `//table/tr/tr` doesn't seem like it would work (tr rows inside tr rows?), so I am a bit surprised. `//table[1]/tr` can be used to limit it to the rows in the first table. The code can be shortened to few lines with LINQ, but LINQ is a bit slower than regular loops because it has some overhead

Comment: @Slai Yep, that's how the page source is written, a `tr` inside a `tr`. I expected it since the router is from my ISP. It's a cheap looking router.